# Excel VBA Cant' Remove Currency Format From Cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I am trying to change an excel file column format from to "Currency" to "Text" by using this VBA code but it is not changing!

```
Private Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, Header As Long

    Header = 2     '<~~ Start row for formatting
    LastRow = 1000 '<~~ Last Row

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        With .Range("C" & Header & ":C" & LastRow)
            '
            '~~> Change format here
            '
            '~~> Number with 5 decimal places.
            .NumberFormat = "@"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

I also tried on new empty (general) column which worked but not on C. Please let me to let you know that even when i try to insert a new column Excel automatically insert it with Currency format! is there any other setting which may affect on this?
Can you please let me know how I can fix this?

Thanks

**Update:**
I also tried this code which didnt work !

```
Sub Clear_Cell_Backgroud()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("C").NumberFormat = "General"
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: The first code works for me. What problems are you facing?

Comment: Hi Siddharth, I do not know for what reason the excel file which we recive auto formats all new inserted Cols to Currency!

Comment: I am able to change the new inserted EMPTY cols to Text by using your code

Comment: May I see a sample of the data and the output that you are expecting?

Comment: But for filled data it doesnt do anything

Comment: like excel? file you mean

Comment: No Give an example of any one cell

Comment: This is an example for Cell C2 082602_DS_001

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43305/discussion-between-user1760110-and-siddharth-rout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me. Ensure that you have the sheet name correct in

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
```

Also in your second code, when you say `Activesheet`, ensure that it is the relevant sheet which is active.

Alternatively avoid the use of `ActiveSheet` and follow what you were doing in the first code. Declare an object and work with it.

If you are working with multiple sheets then your 2nd code can be written as

```
Sub Clear_Cell_Backgroud()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.Columns(3).NumberFormat = "General"
        ws.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    Next ws
End Sub
```